# Use OS X to take pictures with camera connected over usb

Tags: objective-c, macos, swift, camera, usb

I'm currently creating an OS X application that makes use of a 
camera (Nikon D700) to take pictures. Is there any way to create an application that takes pictures?
For instance: I click on a button in my program, and it takes a picture with the camera, and sends it directly back to the program.

The programming language does not really matter.

Any help or related posts are welcome.

Thanks!

Reense